# Reference/vocab request: matrix representation from inner products in non-orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

**Background question:** Suppose $\mathcal{B} = \{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ is a basis for an inner product space $V$, and $T: V \to V$ is a linear operator.  The goal is to find a matrix representation for $T$ in the basis $\mathcal{B}$, expressed in terms of inner products between the basis vectors $v_1, \dots, v_n$ and also their images $Tv_1, \dots, Tv_n$ under the operator.

**Answer to background question:** If we let
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix} 
a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \dots & a_{nn} \end{bmatrix}
$$
be the desired matrix, then for each $i = 1, \dots, n$ it follows that
$$
Tv_i = a_{1i} v_1 + a_{2i} v_2 + \dots + a_{ni} v_n
$$
and taking an inner product on both sides with $v_j$ yields for each $i,j$ the equation
$$
\langle T v_i, v_j \rangle = a_{1i} \langle v_1, v_j \rangle + \dots + a_{ni} \langle v_n, v_j \rangle.
$$
Writing these $n^2$ equations in matrix form,

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \langle T v_1, v_1 \rangle & \langle T v_2, v_1 \rangle & \dots & \langle T v_n, v_1 \rangle \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\langle T v_1, v_n \rangle & \dots & \dots & \langle T v_n, v_n \rangle \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
\langle v_1, v_1 \rangle & \langle v_2, v_1 \rangle & \dots & \langle v_n, v_1 \rangle \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\langle v_n, v_1 \rangle & \dots & \dots & \langle v_n, v_n \rangle
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & \dots & \dots & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Solving yields
$$
M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\langle v_1, v_1 \rangle & \langle v_2, v_1 \rangle & \dots & \langle v_n, v_1 \rangle \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\langle v_n, v_1 \rangle & \dots & \dots & \langle v_n, v_n \rangle
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} \langle T v_1, v_1 \rangle & \langle T v_2, v_1 \rangle & \dots & \langle T v_n, v_1 \rangle \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\langle T v_1, v_n \rangle & \dots & \dots & \langle T v_n, v_n \rangle \end{bmatrix}
$$

**My question:** What to call this procedure/formula, and what (elementary) reference to point students to if they've had one course in linear algebra but haven't seen this.  That matrix getting inverted in the answer is the [Gramian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix), and parts of this calculation look like what they might see in their textbook sections on QR decomposition or SVD.  Is there something more specific to call this result?